# Codeigniter's Validation

Tags: codeigniter, web

Guys I am stuck here in **Codeigniter validation**. The scenario is that I want to display all the *error messages* right below each respective input field and not all the error messages together on the top of the form. Could anyone help me, how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below mentioned code. This will help you.

```
<h5>Username</h5>
<?php echo form_error('username'); ?>
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" size="50" />

<h5>Password</h5>
<?php echo form_error('password'); ?>
<input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>" size="50" />

<h5>Password Confirm</h5>
<?php echo form_error('passconf'); ?>
<input type="text" name="passconf" value="<?php echo set_value('passconf'); ?>" size="50" />

<h5>Email Address</h5>
<?php echo form_error('email'); ?>
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" size="50" />
```

Comment: Can you please show your controller function, so we can help you out from this.

Comment: Ok. Thanks man it's working now. I made a slight mistake that's why it wasn't working. But i appreciate your help!

Comment: @ProgrammingGeek : Glad to help you out from this.

Comment: pleasure is mine!

Answer (score 1):

Use `form_error()` function to do that. As describe in manual

```
echo form_error('username');
```

All you have to do is put this line under the field where you want to see error message. Here `username` is the name of the form field

more details 
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#showing-errors-individually

Comment: Thanks a lot bro.. You rocked!

Answer (score 0):

write below code after your text or drop-down field

```
<?php echo form_error('field_name','<div class="errorClass">','</div>');?>
```